# tty: No such file or directory in bash

Tags: bash

Below is a simple bash program to read from a file.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

echo "Enter file name"
read fname

terminal='tty'
exec<"$fname"

while read line
do
        echo "$line"
done

exec<$terminal
```

It executes fine but it also gives an error

```
[anishjp@fedora22 Bash_programs]$ ./read_file 
Enter file name
source_file
This is a cool file.
How are you doing?
I am glad you used this file.
Hey, where are you going?
./read_file: line 16: tty: No such file or directory
```

How do I remove this error?

Comment: You're setting `$terminal` to the literal string `tty`. Why are you trying to redirect to that filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant:

```
terminal=`tty`
```

Single quotes just return a literal string, backticks or `$()` are for substituting the output of a command.

But you shouldn't use `tty` for this, because the original `stdin` might not be connected to the terminal (the user could have redirected input when running the script). You should save the original `stdin` in another descriptor.

```
exec 3<&0 <"$fname"
...
exec <&3 3<&-
```

There's also no need to use `exec` if you just want to read from a file. You could just redirect the `while` loop to the file:

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line"
done < "$fname"
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution!